# Typescript: Narrow function return type based on parameter

Tags: typescript, generics

I have the following typescript code:

```
  const REPORT_FILTERS = {
    car: 'car',
    bicycle: 'bicycle',
    boat: 'boat',
  } as const;

  type ReportFilters = keyof typeof REPORT_FILTERS;

  // filter comes from the URL queryString, so it’s a string by default
  const { report: filter } = Object.fromEntries([
    ['report', 'car'],
  ]) as {
    report: ReportFilters;
  };


  const whichReport = (report: ReportFilters) => {
    const x = REPORT_FILTERS[report];
    return x;
  };

  const a = whichReport(filter);
```

I want to find a way to cast the result value of the `whichReport` function based on the report value I’m passing.

Ex: If I'm passing “car” as a report parameter, I want the return type of `whichReport` to be “car” and not `”car” | “bicycle” | “boat”`.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [typescript generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html). In your current code the `report` is a union of all possible keys and thus you get all possible values as a return value, which can be fixed by adding a generic parameter constrained to extend `ReportFilters`:

```
const whichReport = <T extends ReportFilters>(report: T) => {
  const x = REPORT_FILTERS[report];
  return x;
};

// const a: "car"
const a = whichReport('car');
```

Comment: Thanks for you anwser @wonderflame. Unfortunately

Comment: Unfortunately??

Comment: Unfortunately I didn’t express myself correctly in the example above. Actually the function parameter `whichReport()` is not a literal like and the old example, it comes from a string variable of the URL query string.  That way I can’t pass it to the function without doing a forced casting to `as ReportFilters` which keeps returning me a composite type. I've updated the example, I'll be grateful if you can help.

Comment: You will need assertion anyway, but you can do [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6&ts=5.0.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBASgUQAoHk4BUD6AxAkgGXQTgGUYBeGAbwCgBIYAQwCcAuGAcieY4Bp6ARgEtgAT2AAbAKbsOwsZKl9BIRlFkDVUZQF8YjCDFCQoAbho0oogA5T4U6yGZRsQiVCnNDlANZTRIABmMFa2QfDIaFh4hMQk5jQA9IkwgW4ezEYgALZShoHMOSEAFnYAqnD4MACOAK6eoiRQzEJgAOa8MBAgMEJQgJgEhoxdza1tMAKiMAAmUoGMte40xtDUMMwOTuqp6Z4wepQoAgBWUsBQAHQFOQhgo3kAFADa9E8cG47OfJzcHAC6-D+AEp9IZaHQPlt2AgAB7NRjnAA8cE2zlc7k8EE6XBYHAAfOYdAlluBVgB3YoiYooz6wSiI9AwKRwqRgaaGGlbdEZCB4h6Q5zsdAg8h46j0FawGEUCKoDA4AhEUhPAVQP7mCFSKC1ZhgGAwwkJSX6GUUqmc5wPNIY5hA0xAA)

Comment: Ok, but it only work for the fixed ‘car’ filter value. Like I mentioned the filter value comes from the URL query string, it can be one of the three values (car, bicycle or boat). Is it possible to have a generic solution for these 3 options?

Comment: if it is not literal and it may be 3 of them, then the response should also be the union of possible values. Not sure what you expect, if you don't know what exactly you are passing. In this case your initial code is okay

Comment: OK, it make sense. I think what I need isn’t possible. I’ll try to change my original code to handle this in a different way. Anyway, thanks for the help.